# How to change the font style of elements in KOMA-Script?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a possibility to change the font-style in the table of contents? Everything I wrote down in my document was written with Times. However, the ToC does not have the same font family. Is there a way to change the font of the ToC to Times New Roman? Thank you : )

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}     
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
Is there a possibility to change the font-style in the table of contents? Everthing I wrote down in my document was written with Times. However, the ToC does not have the same font family. Is there a way to change the font of the ToC to Times New Roman?

\end{document}
```

Comment: The TOC has the same font as the main document. The reason why you must have something special defined. Show in an example that it is different!

Comment: I just guess you want all chaptertitles to be in roman, not sans: `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}`

Comment: Or if the the chapter titles in TOC should be in roman: `\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\rmfamily}`.  Or all headings in your document: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}`

Comment: @esdd Do you wanna write up an answer? We could mark the question by Nico Schlömer in the KOMA tag as a duplicate of this one here. Nico was asking for something about the title, but the question was too unclear to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\setkomafont` or maybe better `\addtokomafont` to change the font settings for an element like the chapter heading.

For all headings in the document the element `disposition` is used first followed by a specific element for the section level. And the element `disposition` is also used for the chapter entries in TOC. Because it is predefined as `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries` all headings in the document will be sans serif while the normal font in the document is still roman.

[image]

If the headings of all section levels including the chapter entries in TOC should be changed to roman use

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

[image]

If the heading of only a specific level should be roman change the settings for its specific element. For example if only the chapter heading should be changed to roman use

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}
```

[image]

If only the font of the chapter entries in TOC should be changed use the element `chapterentry`

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\rmfamily}
```

[image]

You can find a list of predefined elements in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), section »Text markup«.

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
%\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you simply don't want sans serif fonts, use option `sfdefaults=false` (formerly `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`):

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The option simply replaces all `\sffamily` in the default font settings of KOMA-Script. The result would be:

[image: table of contents]

[image: chapter, section, subsection]

So not only the table of contents will not use sans serif fonts any longer but also the headings of chapter, section, subsection etc. and also, e.g., the labels of `description` environment.

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the hint.